# How to provide default parameter value to npm script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, npm

I have this in my `package.json` file:

```
scripts: { 
  "echo": "echo ${1-'/*'}"
}
```

Then when I run `npm run echo` I get `/*` which is what I want (It denotes all paths from the root. That's the default.)

But, when I run `npm run echo /salad`, I get `/* /salad` which is not helpful. It seems to be using the default, adding a space, and then adding the parameter.

How do I get just `/salad` when I provide a parameter, and `/*` when I don't provide a parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

npm script arguments are just appended to the end, so they will not correctly resolve numeric variables like `$1`.

To make such variables resolve, you can wrap your script in a shell function and then execute the function. Try this:

```
scripts: { 
  "echo": "run(){ echo ${1-'/*'}; }; run"
}
```

Alternatively, just use named variables in your script instead of numeric ones.

Comment: Hmmm... any chance there's a way I can pass in any number of variables?